# Variable not binded correctly (inception)

Tags: angularjs

alert-reset-password-response.html:

```
<span data-ng-bind="responseInfo"></span>
```

js:

```
$scope.language.resetPassword.responseInfo = 'Redirecting in {{responseTime}} seconds.';
$scope.responseTime = 3;
$scope.responseInfo = $interpolate($scope.language.resetPassword.responseInfo)($scope);

angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('alert-container')[0]).append($compile($templateCache.get('alert-reset-password-response.html'))($scope));

setInterval(function () {
    $scope.responseTime = $scope.responseTime - 1;
    $scope.$apply();
    console.log($scope.responseTime); // <-- this displays the count down correct in the console (2, 1, 0...)
    if ($scope.responseTime === 0)
        $window.location.href = '/';
}, 1000);
```

I get the feeling I haven't binded `{{responseTime}}` correctly, it just sits at the initial number of `3` (meaning the `{{responseTime}}` isn't binded).